# Changing content of UITextView by pressing button.

Tags: swift, uibutton, uitextview

I'm new to swift programming, so this may be a dumb question, but how can I change the content of an UITextView Object by pressing a button.

The example I tested looks like this:

```
@IBOutlet weak var dataButton: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var dataView: UITextView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
}


@IBAction func testButtonPressed(sender: UIButton) {
    dataView.text = "Test worked."
}
```

Actually it doesn't work. My Storyboard has a ViewController from the Class where the above code is written. I also have the Button and the TextLabel. Do I need to specify anything in the Interface Builder or is something wrong with my code?

Thanks in advance for any help!!!

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that your IBOutlet's and IBActions are connected in storyboard. It should work. You could set a breakpoint at the line with: `dataView.text = "Test worked."` to see if the code is reached. If it doesn't reach the breakpoint then your IBAction is not connected properly.

Comment: Thanks, it turned out I didn't connect the Outlets and Actions properly to the storyboard. Now it works!

Answer (score 0):

`IBAction`'s `sender` parameter need an underscore before it, that is:

```
@IBAction func testButtonPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
    dataView.text = "Test worked."
}
```

are you sure you connected the code correctly?